# Synapse Apache pool: how many concurrent sessions (notebooks) are possible for one apache pool?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I am new in using synapse workspace.

Could any one help, how many concurrent notebooks are possible for one apache pool?

My apache pool configuration:

- 4vcore 32 gb
- Number of nodes - 3 to 10
- Auto pausing is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

After spending time on this, i got an answer myself. Synapse triggered below message when i am trying more than one sessions ( notebooks) on apache spark.

That shows, it depends on how many cores you have in your account and how many you are requesting. If it exceeds it will throw error.

[image]